# Is the power company responsible for trimming trees with power lines running through?

Tags: contract-law, safety, trees

Previous tree trimmers would not approach areas of trees near the lines in St. Johns County Florida.  They indicated power company owns this.  Power company claims that they are near service drop and is customer responsibility:  in limbo.

Although the tree is on private property, the lines do run through the trees.

What is the process to determine if FPL (power company) owns this responsibility of trimming tree branches proximal to power lines?

[image]

Comment: What jurisdiction is this? If it's in the United States, I cannot imagine 'ownership' of the tree being the domain of anything but local government, i.e. city council, etc. Of course, compliance with safety standards could be a matter that is under the control of a broader governing body (i.e. state or federal government).

Comment: This is going to be highly jurisdictional dependent. I believe that my power company has a limited right to trim or remove trees that may interfere with power lines, but not an obligation and are certainly not the "owners" of the tree.

Comment: Good questions.  Posting updated with responses